# Universal License key for VMware Workstation pro 16, why is it free?

Tags: vmware-workstation

So, my VMware license expired and I needed a new one fast for school, I went on github and found a license (ZF3R0-FHED2-M80TY-8QYGC-NPKYF) and it worked! 
I was surprised since I entered it as a joke with my friends.. 
It seems that multiple people are using this key and I thought this seemed kinda sketchy.. I went on google to find out more about it and it seems that there is a thing called a Universal License Key which is used for previous versions for free but with limited features. 
Though I didn't find a source I can fully trust, so my question stands: 
What is a Universal License Key? 
Are there any dangers?

I know this might be a stupid question, but I couldn't find an answer while searching on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like for Sublime Text, a paid/given leaked key that can be found on the web and that was not blacklisted (yet?) by the company.

It being universal is probably saying that this work from anywhere and is not really limited anyhow.

The danger of using it? Probably none, but you could maybe experience your software to be downgraded one day because this one will expire or will get discarded by the company.